# Como são implementados os modificadores em TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, typescript

TypeScript suporta todas as funcionalidades presentes em JavaScript (propriamente dito ECMAScript 6), além de possuir modificadores, tais como: `private`, `protected` e `abstract`. Porém, em ES6 não existe estes modificadores.

Para "emular" o modificador `private` é possível realizar algo do tipo:

```
class MyObject {

    constructor(attr, myArray) {
        this._attr = attr;
        this._myArray = myArray;
        Object.freeze(this);
    }

    get attr(){
        return this._attr;
    }

    get myArray(){
        return [].concat(myArray);
    }
}
```

Agora os modificadores `protected` e `abstract` eu não faço ideia de como implementar algo equivalente em JavaScript puro (vanilla). Desta forma, gostaria ver quais soluções são possível para "emular" tais operadores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O compilador do TypeScript gera um código JS e pode ser visto como ele implementa. Pode fazer [pela web](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Employee%20extends%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20department%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20department%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.department%20%3D%20department%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getElevatorPitch()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%60Hello%2C%20my%20name%20is%20%24%7Bthis.name%7D%20and%20I%20work%20in%20%24%7Bthis.department%7D.%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20howard%20%3D%20new%20Employee(%22Howard%22%2C%20%22Sales%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(howard.getElevatorPitch())%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(howard.name)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20Department%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printName()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Department%20name%3A%20%22%20%2B%20this.name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20printMeeting()%3A%20void%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20be%20implemented%20in%20derived%20classes%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AccountingDepartment%20extends%20Department%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(%22Accounting%20and%20Auditing%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20constructors%20in%20derived%20classes%20must%20call%20super()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printMeeting()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22The%20Accounting%20Department%20meets%20each%20Monday%20at%2010am.%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20generateReports()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Generating%20accounting%20reports...%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20department%3A%20Department%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%20to%20create%20a%20reference%20to%20an%20abstract%20type%0D%0Adepartment%20%3D%20new%20Department()%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20cannot%20create%20an%20instance%20of%20an%20abstract%20class%0D%0Adepartment%20%3D%20new%20AccountingDepartment()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%20to%20create%20and%20assign%20a%20non-abstract%20subclass%0D%0Adepartment.printName()%3B%0D%0Adepartment.printMeeting()%3B%0D%0Adepartment.generateReports()%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20method%20doesn%27t%20exist%20on%20declared%20abstract%20type).

```
class Person {
    protected name: string;
    constructor(name: string) { this.name = name; }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    private department: string;

    constructor(name: string, department: string) {
        super(name);
        this.department = department;
    }

    public getElevatorPitch() {
        return `Hello, my name is ${this.name} and I work in ${this.department}.`;
    }
}

let howard = new Employee("Howard", "Sales");
console.log(howard.getElevatorPitch());
console.log(howard.name); // error

abstract class Department {

    constructor(public name: string) {
    }

    printName(): void {
        console.log("Department name: " + this.name);
    }

    abstract printMeeting(): void; // must be implemented in derived classes
}

class AccountingDepartment extends Department {

    constructor() {
        super("Accounting and Auditing"); // constructors in derived classes must call super()
    }

    printMeeting(): void {
        console.log("The Accounting Department meets each Monday at 10am.");
    }

    generateReports(): void {
        console.log("Generating accounting reports...");
    }
}

let department: Department; // ok to create a reference to an abstract type
department = new Department(); // error: cannot create an instance of an abstract class
department = new AccountingDepartment(); // ok to create and assign a non-abstract subclass
department.printName();
department.printMeeting();
department.generateReports(); // error: method doesn't exist on declared abstract type
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Modificators.ts).

#### JavaScript

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return Person;
}());
var Employee = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Employee, _super);
    function Employee(name, department) {
        var _this = _super.call(this, name) || this;
        _this.department = department;
        return _this;
    }
    Employee.prototype.getElevatorPitch = function () {
        return "Hello, my name is " + this.name + " and I work in " + this.department + ".";
    };
    return Employee;
}(Person));
var howard = new Employee("Howard", "Sales");
console.log(howard.getElevatorPitch());
console.log(howard.name); // error
var Department = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Department(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Department.prototype.printName = function () {
        console.log("Department name: " + this.name);
    };
    return Department;
}());
var AccountingDepartment = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(AccountingDepartment, _super);
    function AccountingDepartment() {
        return _super.call(this, "Accounting and Auditing") || this;
    }
    AccountingDepartment.prototype.printMeeting = function () {
        console.log("The Accounting Department meets each Monday at 10am.");
    };
    AccountingDepartment.prototype.generateReports = function () {
        console.log("Generating accounting reports...");
    };
    return AccountingDepartment;
}(Department));
var department; // ok to create a reference to an abstract type
department = new Department(); // error: cannot create an instance of an abstract class
department = new AccountingDepartment(); // ok to create and assign a non-abstract subclass
department.printName();
department.printMeeting();
department.generateReports(); // error: method doesn't exist on declared abstract type
```

Então o membro protegido na verdade é privado, e é mesmo, só que na extensão ele dá um acesso especial à classe base.

Pode estar se perguntando como garante que não é acessado algo sem permissão. Simples, o compilador não aceita código que faz isto. E aí deve perguntar se pode modificar o JS de `Employee` e acessar o que não deve. Sim, pode, é como estivesse acessando por reflexão, está subvertendo as garantias da linguagens acessando o código gerado. O acesso fora da classe não pode ser feito porque o JS oferece essa garantia

O método abstrato simplesmente não é gerado, como ele é um contrato só o compilador TS precisa saber que ele existe.